# Kendo UI datasource issue

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid that we are using on a search page:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SMT.Models.SpecimenDetail>()
    .Name("SpecimenDetailGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.uniqueID).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(e => e.contact_business_email).Width(120).Title("Owner Email");
        columns.Bound(e => e.contact_business_phone).Width(120).Title("Owner Phone");
    })
    .ToolBar(tools =>
            {
                tools.Excel();
                tools.Custom().Text("Back to Specimen Summary").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "goBack", style = "margin-left: 880px;" });
            })
    .Excel(excel => excel
        .AllPages(true)
        .FileName("SpecimenDetailGridData.xlsx")
        .Filterable(true)
        .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Home"))
        )
    .Resizable(x => x.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(x => x.Columns(true))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:500px;" })
    .Pageable()
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
        .Ajax()
                .Model(model => { 
                    model.Id(p => p.uniqueID);
                    model.Field(p => p.SampleID).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(p => p.company_business_name).Editable(false);

                    // disable company name on edit
                    // model.Field(p => p.company_business_name).Editable(false);
                })
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetSpecimenDetail", "Home").Data("FillSearchParms"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateSpecimen", "Home").Data("FillUpdateParms"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteSpecimen", "Home"))
        .PageSize(10)
        .Events(e => { e.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd");})
        )
)
```

And on that same page, we have a button that calls a jQuery function that refreshes the grid:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#SearchBtn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#divSearchSpecimenDetail").attr("style", "display: block;");

        var grid = $("#SpecimenDetailGrid").data("kendoGrid");

        //think this is the problem
        grid.datasource.data = "FillSearchParams";
        grid.dataSource.read();
        grid.refresh();

        e.preventDefault();
        hideColumns(specimenCat);

        $("#searchbar").data("kendoPanelBar").collapse($("li.k-state-active"));
    })
});
```

and another jQuery function that selects the search paramters:

```
function FillSearchParms() {
    var units = defaultDDObj("Units");
    var specimenCat = defaultDD("SpecimenCategory");

    //debugger;

    var searchParms = {
        SpecimenCategory: specimenCat,
        Units: units.Value,

        uniqueID: $("#uniqueID").val(),
        SampleID: $("#SampleID").val(),

        ThicknessAtWeld1From: $("#ThicknessAtWeld1From").val(),
        ThicknessAtWeld1To: $("#ThicknessAtWeld1To").val(),

        OverlayThicknessFrom: $("#OverlayThicknessFrom").val(),
        OverlayThicknessTo: $("#OverlayThicknessTo").val(),

    }
```

The problem is, for whatever reason clicking the button is calling the read action, but not the FillSearchParams call.  Newer to Kendo, and jQuery, so I think I'm just formatting the line:

```
grid.datasource.data = "FillSearchParams";
```

in the button call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What formal parameter is defined at the controller for the jquery call? You are adding an extra json wrapper to the data when you return searchParms.

Comment: public ActionResult GetSpecimenDetail([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest x, SpecimenDetail request)

x has been the problem here, for whatever reason if the call comes from the grid it works, just not from the button.

Comment: I think the data function should return a SpecimenDetail{ } to match what is expected.

Comment: I'm not trying to return searchParams, I'm trying to pass them.

Comment: Whatever FillSearchParms returns will be the data object sent to your controller method. You need to return data from FillSearchParms.

Comment: Ahhhh, okay, I see what you're saying.  Here's why I was confused.  In the Kendo grid setup, it's passing FillSearchParams as a parameter, I thought I could do it the same way in the jQuery function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add this line in the jQuery call:

grid.dataSource.page(1);